# Should a compact nbd of $p$ contain some open nbd containing $p$?

Tags: general-topology

If some topological space $X$ is locally compact, then each point of $X$ has at least one compact neighborhood. The book I'm reading now doesn't mention if such compact neighborhood of a point should contain an open neighborhood of the point. Would it be fair to assume that such compact neighborhood of a point contain some open neighborhood of the point?

Comment: If we are agree on the definition of "neighborhood", then yes. A neighborhood of $p$ is a set $U$ such that there is an open set $O \subseteq U$ with $p \in O$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise compact neighborhood would be a generalization of "points", i.e. every point is a compact neighborhood of itself, hence every space would be locally compact. That does not sounds reasonable.